# Call Scala code from Java?

Tags: java, scala, interop, scala-java-interop

I'm using Netbeans to write Scala and Java.

Netbeans generated a .jar file for the Scala project. I tried importing that file in the Java project. But I couldn't import any class from that .jar file into my Java project.

I also tried importing scala-library.jar to the java project, and could import classes from that jar.

I want to write my library in Scala, then expose a small interface that only involves Java stuff, then write a Java wrapper so that people can use it as a Java package. Is that possible? How do I do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you do have time to track down what went wrong, it would be helpful to place the answer here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be no problem in doing this.

1. Have you verified (e.g. using WinZip or the `jar` utility) that your `.jar` file actually contains the relevant `.class` files? (use `jar tvf mylib.jar` to check)
2. If you have verified that the correct `.class` files exist in your `jar` file, what is the runtime error you are seeing? Is it a `NoClassDefFoundError`? If so, which `class` cannot be found? How are you referring to the (Scala) class in your (Java) code?

Comment: Oh thank you. It turned out this was due to my lack of knowledge in Java. I compared my package with scala-library.jar then do the following: 1. make sure all classes and sub-packages were under the same root package 2. edit the MANIFEST.MF file, with the one from scala-library.jar as a sample Then I could call my Scala classes from Java. I'm still not clear where the problem is from, but I'm in a hurry now. I'll find out later. Thank you very much :)